# Flutter Multi Horizontal lists

Tags: flutter

I have tried a ton of layouts and widgets. Each time I get a new exception message. Basically, I aim to have multiple horizontal lists under each other.

Note: I can't use `ListView.builder` because the items don't start loaded but rather each item loads after 6 seconds.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: store.coins.map((coin) => ListTilWidgetFirst(coin)).toList(),
      );
      }



class ListTilWidgetFirst extends StatelessWidget {
  ListTilWidgetFirst(this.coin);
  final Channel coin;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container( height: 300.0,
      child: Card(
              child:
              ListTile(
                  leading: new Image.network(
                    coin.img,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    width: 150.0,
                    height: 40.0,
                  ),
                  title: new Text(
                    coin.name,
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  subtitle: new Text(
                    coin.name,
                    style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0),
                  ),

              ),

      ),
    );
  }
}




// to be views in anotehr class 



class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body:Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            CategorySecond()
          ],
        )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't really do a great job of showing what you've tried, and your explanation of what you're trying to do is slightly lacking, but I think I can help anyways. But in the future, it would be better to include the code from as far as you got along with the error you received.

The following code shows three lists that start initially empty, then are filled with data (simulating loading).

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Multiple horizontal lists")),
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UrlObject {
  final String url;

  UrlObject(this.url);
}

Stream<List<UrlObject>> generate(int num, Duration timeout) async* {
  List<UrlObject> list = [];
  int seed = Random().nextInt(200);
  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    await Future.delayed(timeout);
    yield list..add(UrlObject("https://loremflickr.com/640/480/dog?random=$i$seed"));
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Stream<List<UrlObject>> stream1;
  Stream<List<UrlObject>> stream2;
  Stream<List<UrlObject>> stream3;

  @override
  void initState() {
    stream1 = generate(10, Duration(seconds: 1, milliseconds: 500));
    stream2 = generate(20, Duration(seconds: 1));
    stream3 = generate(30, Duration(seconds: 2));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children: [
        streamItems(stream1, (context, list) => HList(objects: list)),
        streamItems(stream2, (context, list) => HList(objects: list)),
        streamItems(stream3, (context, list) => HList(objects: list)),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget streamItems(Stream stream, Widget builder(BuildContext context, List<UrlObject> objects)) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      initialData: new List<UrlObject>(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) => builder(context, snapshot.data),
      stream: stream,
    );
  }
}

class HList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<UrlObject> objects;

  const HList({Key key, this.objects}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 250.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: objects.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return new AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 3.0 / 2.0,
            child: Image.network(
              objects[index].url,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm going to take a guess at why you're having issues. The way that Flutter lays out thing relies on a few things - in particular, the way that widgets size themselves is important. They tend to use an enclosing widget's size if it is explicit, or otherwise size themselves to their children.

In the case of a listview that doesn't have any children yet, it may not know how to size itself if you don't specify the height so it throws an exception. Widgets will also throw exceptions if they are too big for the space given to them, or if you have something that can expand infinitely inside something that can expand infinitely (for example if you have a horizontal list in a horizontal list - the inner one expands to the biggest constraint it has in it's main axis, but because it's in another horizontal list that maximum is infinity, which causes an exception).

EDIT:

I've modified the above code to show this using streams. Note that you don't actually need to generate a List<...> if you don't want to - you could return individual items instead. If you were to do that, you'd simply need to keep track of a list in a member variable in a stateful widget's state. You don't need to call setState though because the StreamBuilder handles that part of it. I personally prefer writing a small function to aggregate the results as it results in cleaner code, but that's a personal preference and might not really be best practices.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Multiple horizontal lists")),
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UrlObject {
  final String url;

  UrlObject(this.url);
}

Stream<UrlObject> generate(int num, Duration timeout) async* {
  int seed = Random().nextInt(200);
  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    await Future.delayed(timeout);
    yield UrlObject("https://loremflickr.com/640/480/dog?random=$i$seed");
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Stream<UrlObject> stream1;
  Stream<UrlObject> stream2;
  Stream<UrlObject> stream3;

  @override
  void initState() {
    stream1 = generate(10, Duration(seconds: 1, milliseconds: 500));
    stream2 = generate(20, Duration(seconds: 1));
    stream3 = generate(30, Duration(seconds: 2));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children: [
        StreamedItemHolder(stream: stream1, builder: (context, list) => HList(objects: list)),
        StreamedItemHolder(stream: stream2, builder: (context, list) => HList(objects: list)),
        StreamedItemHolder(stream: stream3, builder: (context, list) => HList(objects: list)),
      ],
    );
  }
}

typedef Widget UrlObjectListBuilder(BuildContext context, List<UrlObject> objects);

class StreamedItemHolder extends StatefulWidget {
  final UrlObjectListBuilder builder;
  final Stream<UrlObject> stream;

  const StreamedItemHolder({Key key, @required this.builder, @required this.stream}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  StreamedItemHolderState createState() => new StreamedItemHolderState();
}

class StreamedItemHolderState extends State<StreamedItemHolder> {
  List<UrlObject> items = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) items.add(snapshot.data);
        return widget.builder(context, items);
      },
      stream: widget.stream,
    );
  }
}

class HList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<UrlObject> objects;

  const HList({Key key, this.objects}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 250.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: objects.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return new AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 3.0 / 2.0,
            child: Image.network(
              objects[index].url,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And as I mentioned in a comment, I haven't used the exact same widget structure or objects as you did, partly because you didn't include an example that showed them fully and partly because it's more useful for you to learn something than simply copy-paste code from someone else.

Edit 2: This is an extremely long explanation I've now realized... the TLDR is that you need to specify the width of each of the list items or else flutter doesn't know how to size them. But it's worth a read as it hopefully explains why that's the case.

Looking at the example tutorial for what you're trying to recreate (it wasn't immediately obvious that's what you were using in the question), the problem is actually to do with the width of the children.

I'll give you a bit of background about how layout is done in flutter as that's what's  causing you problems.

When a widget does a layout pass, it either has a specified size, uses its parent's size (or a percentage thereof), or uses its children's size. For example, if have a blank app with the following, the Container takes up the entire screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyWidget());

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: Colors.red);
  }
}
```

If you specify a height and a width on that container, it will actually still stay the same size though, which is slightly confusing until you think about it.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 200.0,
      width: 200.0,
    );
  }
}
```

What is happening is that the container wants to size itself to the size you've given it, but if it were to do so it wouldn't know how to position itself within its parent. So instead it stays the same size as the parent.

If you wrap it in a widget that allows it to not be constrained by the size of its parent, for example an Align or Center, it will then be the size you tell it to be.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 200.0,
        width: 200.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That results in a red square in the top left. But if instead you don't specify a height and width, but do specify a child it now sizes itself to its child.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text(
            "Some Text",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, decoration: null),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That results in a text widget in the middle of the screen (ignore the Directionality widget, it's just there because I'm not using a MaterialApp and it's needed for Text if you don't use MaterialApp). If you then want to put it in a Column the behaviour changes again though. Without a child, the container will size itself to the smallest it's allowed to be (which happens to be zero).

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you do use a child, the container will then size itself to that child. Now say you have two children and you want one of them to take all of the available space. For that you use an Expanded.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text(
                  "Some Text",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, decoration: null),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text(
                "Some More Text",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, decoration: null),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Notice how the expanded makes it take all available space in the main (vertical) axis, but not in the horizontal axis. Now that's covered, lets move on to something like the example you're working with.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Some Text",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, decoration: null),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There's a couple of things to observe here. The first is the ListView which is vertical, just like the coin list you're having problems with. And the child is a row that expands *to fit the size of the ListView* **horizontally**. The IntrinsicHeight is basically to tell the row to be the height of the biggest of it's children (the text) so that the coloured container will be that same height as well.

Now, to switch this list to be horizontal, there's technically only one step that's needed - setting the ListView's `scrollDirection` to `Axis.horizontal`. However, and this is a big however... this then causes the exception you've no doubt been seeing.

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.

That line isn't particularly helpful, but the rest of it should be.

> When a row is in a parent that does not provide a finite width constraint, for example if it is in a horizontal scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the horizontal axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the horizontal direction.
>
> These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
>
> Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.

Don't get caught up on the RenderFlex part. What it's saying is because your ListView is now horizontal, its' children can now theoretically expand to infinity in the horizontal direction. One of those children (the only one really) is a Row which has an Expanded child. That means that the expanded will try to size to the biggest the row can be, which happens to be infinity.

The fairly simple solution is to give the child a fixed width.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 200.0,
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Some Text",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, decoration: null),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That expands to the full size of the screen, but you'll be wrapping in a Row/vertical Listview so it'll size itself properly.

One thing to consider is that instead of setting an explicit width on a child, you might want your child to be sized based on the parent height. That does mean that the parent needs an explicit height though.

Here's an example of that:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 200.0,
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [1, 2]
                .map(
                  (v) => AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 1.5,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Some Text",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, decoration: null),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So for the tutorial, that looks like this:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with StoreWatcherMixin<HomeScreen> {
  CoinStore store;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    store = listenToStore(coinStoreToken);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flux Crypto Ticker'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
            onPressed: () {
              print("Loading coins");
              loadCoinsAction.call();
            },
            child: Text('Get Coins'),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 200.0,
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: store.coins.map((coin) => CoinWidget(coin)).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CoinWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  CoinWidget(this.coin);

  final Coin coin;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
      child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 5.0),
          ),
          child: Card(
            elevation: 10.0,
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(coin.name),
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      child: Text(
                        coin.symbol,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 13.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      radius: 90.0,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text("\$${coin.price.toStringAsFixed(2)}"),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

And for the record, you actually *should* be using a builder in that tutorial. You're not, so it's actually having to instantiate each and everyone of those objects then the list is first created rather than building them on demand as the view is scrolled. To fix that you can replace your ListView with this:

```
ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: store.coins.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) => CoinWidget(store.coins[i]),
            ),
```

Just so you know though - when I tested this out, it wouldn't actually rebuild once the list had been loaded by pressing the Get Coins button, at least until I did a hot reload. That's because the state isn't being propagated properly by the flutter flux framework, which seems to be a design flaw. If you aren't seeing that then ignore this, but if you do I'd recommend opening a new issue about that as this answer is more than long enough already and I personally don't like flux so you'll have to find someone else to help with it.

Comment: Your code works but dose not solve my issue, you specified the mount of items in initState, in my case its one list comes from stream. Secondly, i want to show it in another class, See the commented code before the last widget in my code which is where i intend to show the list from the other class. Building sth like this, [link] https://github.com/tensor-programming/Flutter_Flux_Tutorial many stores, each one is a horizontal list under each other in the main screen which is separate class.

Comment: Ah, fair. That's information that would have been good to include in the question as it wasn't clear it was coming from a stream rather than just a query. Still, it's simple enough to do that part of it. And I didn't use the exact widget you've specified because I don't want to go about making a bunch of name + img objects but rather do something which shows the core concept. From what I've done you should be able to figure out how to use coins instead. I will update with streams though.

Comment: Hi, you are right, i should have explained better, still dose not resolve my issue, can you check the link in my first comment please, so you could get better idea on what i am facing, dealing with flux stores is not like calling a rest or changing it to stream, the structure is whole different i spent hours trying to figure it out still, no luck. once you seen the link it will be clear, you will see a store fetched into vertical list, what i aim for is to have it horizontally, plus other stores under it horizontally. dose it make a sense?

Comment: Ah, okay. To be honest using stores as they do in that example actually makes this a lot simpler. They already handle all the stream/state stuff for you, and you just need to use the store to create the list. So all you need to do is set the list to be horizonal _and give it a height_ (e.g. by wrapping it in a container), and it should do what you want. I'll post some code for you to take a look at in a minute.

Comment: Ah, looked at it a bit more and it's actually the width of the children that's causing the problem in the example.  I've updated the answer with what is probably much too much information, but hopefully it's an interesting read at least.